# How to send multiple responses (FileResponse as well as JsonResponse) in fast-api?

Tags: fastapi

I know how to send any file via **FileResponse** and also know how to send plaintext or custom Response in **fast-api**. However, I cannot figure as to how can I send info as Json **along with** a large file attachment. My need is to send information as Json along with file as attachment. Thanks